# OnClientClick not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

The onClientClick event is not getting fired in IE11 browser, however the same piece of code is working perfectly fine in IE8,9 and 10 browsers. Is there any extra piece of code that i need to add in there.

```
     <table width="100%">   
                    <tr>             
                     <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFTCancel" Text="Cancel"            
                    OnClientClick="return confirmCancel();" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"/>       
                    </td>
                     <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnApprove" Text="Approve" Enabled="false"            
                    OnClientClick="return confirmApprove();" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"/>       
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>  


<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmCancel() {
            var returnvalue;
            $("#btnFTCancel").css("cursor", "text");
            returnvalue = confirm('Transactions generated for this request ID will be cancelled. Do you wish to continue ?');
            return returnvalue;
        }

        function confirmApprove() {
            var returnvalue;
            returnvalue = confirm('Transactions generated for this request ID will be sent to FCS. Do you wish to continue ?');
            return returnvalue;
       }
        function setBtnCursor() {
            $("input[type='submit']").css('cursor', 'pointer');
             $("input[type='submit'][disabled='disabled']").css('cursor', 'default');
         }

    </script>
```

TIA,

Amit

Comment: What you have in onclick handler, there would be something in that is breaking the execution

Comment: in which control your are binding this event?

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig aspnet button..
 It is not related to something inside since it is not even hitting the first line inside the function.

Comment: could you please share your code and markup by edit your question.

Comment: Updated the question with the code..

Comment: try `OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmCancel();" `

Comment: Let me try that. however i feel that it wont have much effect as the above piece of code is working fine in IE10, IE9 without any issues